# Google Cloud Functions - Test/Mock with Authentication for HTTP triggered functions?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-functions

I have an API built using GCP Cloud Functions, I know it's built upon Flask, however the app itself is not exposed to the user.

From the [Testing Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing) for GCP Cloud Functions it uses the `Mock` object from `unittest` built in from Python.

However, I have an authentication decorator that I can throw around and it detects if there is an appropriate password in the `x-api-key` on the header.

```
"""Authentication for Cloud Functions."""

from functools import partial, wraps

from flask import request, abort

import config


def auth(func=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(auth)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.headers.get('x-api-key') and request.headers.get('x-api-key') == config.API_KEY:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401)
    return wrap
```

Then I can apply it onto a Google Cloud Functions:

```
@auth
@log_func
def frontend_query(request):
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)

    # Do Something Else
```

You can use `mock` to create a `request_json`, but how do I also get fake header data into `request.headers`?